# Как задать одинаковый порядок уведомлений в Notification Drawer на всех версиях Android

Tags: android, android-notification

Иногда мое приложение создает несколько уведомлений. Причем, мне хотелось бы, чтобы они располагались в Navigation Drawer в определенном порядке. Выяснилось, что они сортируются в соответствии с параметром `time` в `.setWhen(time)`. Но беда в том, что на некоторых версиях ОС самыми верхними оказываются самые новые, а на других - самые старые.

Попытка использовать `.setSortKey(String.valueOf(appearanceOrder))` также не увенчалась успехом, так как не на всех версиях ОС это работает.

Как добиться желаемого расположения нескольких уведомлений моего приложения на всех версиях ОС?

Может быть как-то можно узнать, как они сортируются (чем новее, тем выше - или наоборот) на данном устройстве?